# Can't update state when using `setFoo` as a callback for websocket `onmessage` event

Tags: reactjs, websocket, closures, react-hooks, react-state-management

**Goal:**

I'm trying to get messages from a server through a websocket connection and add them to an array of objects called `outgoingMessages`.

**Problem:**

Only the newest message is saved in `outgoingMessages` when `receive()` is called.

I suspect this happens because `Websocket.onmessage` only uses the value of `outgoingMessages` from the time when I call `connect()`. I've tried fiddling around with it quite a bit, but I haven't been able to fix this issue.

How can I get `receive()` to use the current state, not the initial one?

Thanks in advance.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [incomingMessages, setIncomingMessages] = React.useState([]);
  const ws = React.useRef(null);

  const receive = (message) => {
    setIncomingMessages([...incomingMessages, message]);
  };

  const connect = () => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket(WS_URL + "mqtt/ws/messages");
    ws.current.onopen = () => setWsConnected(true);
    ws.current.onclose = () => setWsConnected(false);
    ws.current.onmessage = (event) => receive(event);
  };

  return (<>Stuff</>)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the `connect` function is called once in the initial render and in the `receive` function, the `incomingMessages` value is always obtained from the `closure` and hence you only see the latest message.

To set state, use functional set state pattern i.e provide a callback to setIncomingMessages.

**Like this**

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [outgoingMessages, setOutgoingMessages] = React.useState([]);
  const ws = React.useRef(null);

  const receive = (message) => {
    setIncomingMessages(prev => [...prev, message]);
  };

  const connect = () => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket(WS_URL + "mqtt/ws/messages");
    ws.current.onopen = () => setWsConnected(true);
    ws.current.onclose = () => setWsConnected(false);
    ws.current.onmessage = (event) => receive(event);
  };

  return (<>Stuff</>)
}
```

p.s. -- just a quick note - your state deals with `outgoingMessages` but you do set state for incomingMessages`in`receive` fun. So have a check on that...

Comment: A nube question: how does `connect` get called?